# Check if WSE 3.0 is already installed

Tags: .net, web-services, installation, wse

I am ready to distribute a small utility to a large number of customers.
This utility requires **WSE 3.0** (Web Service Enhancements) installed on the client machine because it needs to connect to a web service on which I don't have any control.
In the setup package I have included the redistributable [MSI from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14089).
Now, I wish to execute the install action only if on the client machine the WSE isn't already installed.
How to check this? Any registry key, componentID or whatelse?

Comment: You _do_ know that WSE is obsolete, right?

Comment: I know, but I can't connect to that pesky service (java) without it..

Comment: Have you tried using "Add Service Reference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if a registry key exists before installing

http://keystrokeesbnet.codeplex.com/discussions/228604